Server Error (500) and strange symbols inside a form
I set up a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu server as OS. I followed this guide: Guide from digitalocean
It all seemed to work good until I opened a page with a form that looks some kind of strange (unwanted brackets before and after "Name:":

The code behind looks like this:
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   def __str__(self) -> str:
      return self.name

# forms.py
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      fields="__all__"
      model = Category

      widgets = {
         'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
      }

# views.py
def categories(request: HttpRequest):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      filledForm = CategoryForm(data=request.POST)
      if filledForm.is_valid():
         newCategory = filledForm
         newCategory.save()

   categoryForm = CategoryForm()
   categories = Category.objects.order_by('name')
   args = {
     'categoryForm': categoryForm,
     'categories': categories,
   }
   return render(request, 'categories.html', args)

And the HTML code:
<div class="container">
    <h2>Categories</h2>
    
    <br>
    
    <form action="{% url 'categories' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ categoryForm }}
        <input type="submit" class="form-control btn-secondary" name="submit-new-category" value="Add">
    </form>
    
    <br>
    
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
            {% for category in categories %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'category_edit' category.id %}">
                        <div>
                            {{ category.name }}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

When I try to post a filled Category-Form, Apache answers with a Server Error (500).
I checked the log file (/var/log/apache2/error.log), but there is nothing else than warnings and notices:
[Sun Aug 11 13:40:06.992377 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2809:tid 281473660837920] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 11 13:40:06.993125 2024] [core:notice] [pid 2809:tid 281473660837920] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 11 13:40:54.766803 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2809:tid 281473660837920] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Aug 11 13:41:05.325303 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3058:tid 281473704566816] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 11 13:41:05.326039 2024] [core:notice] [pid 3058:tid 281473704566816] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 11 14:28:47.835081 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3058:tid 281473704566816] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Aug 11 14:28:48.320266 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3971:tid 281473052844064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 11 14:28:48.321026 2024] [core:notice] [pid 3971:tid 281473052844064] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 11 14:30:37.648045 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3971:tid 281473052844064] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Aug 11 14:33:43.893787 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 912:tid 281472884133920] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 11 14:33:43.906803 2024] [core:notice] [pid 912:tid 281472884133920] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Aug 11 14:41:50.770637 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 912:tid 281472884133920] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Aug 11 14:41:54.169218 2024] [core:warn] [pid 912:tid 281472884133920] AH00045: child process 915 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Sun Aug 11 14:45:14.149261 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 923:tid 281472851755040] AH00489: Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/5.0.0 Python/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 11 14:45:14.160107 2024] [core:notice] [pid 923:tid 281472851755040] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

running it on my development computer with python manage.py runserver works all fine.
Now, I have two questions: Why do those brackets appear in my Category form and why am I getting the Server error? I posted both questions in the same thread, because I do not know, if they are related or not.

Is that the actual indentation of your code? Or did the indentation get screwed up when you copy/pasted it? Since indentation is critical in Python code, please fix the indentation of the code in your question to be the the same as your actual code you are running, otherwise everyone is just going to tell you that the problem is probably due to incorrect code indentation.

Identation mistakes came from copy-pasting. Thank you for the hint. I should have checked it before posting


Brackets Appearing in the Category Form
 
 {% csrf_token %}
 
     {{ categoryForm.name.label_tag }}
     {{ categoryForm.name }}
 
 



Server Error (500) when Submitting the Form
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
'file': {
'level': 'DEBUG',
'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
},
},
'loggers': {
'django': {
'handlers': ['file'],
'level': 'DEBUG',
'propagate': True,
},
},
}


Check for Potential Issues in the Code
if filledForm.is_valid():
newCategory = filledForm.save(commit=False)
newCategory.save()

